# How to get instance ID of created EC2 instance

Tags: aws-cdk

Trying to get the instance ID of an EC2 instance created by CF (generated by AWS CDK), this used to work in at least v0.28:

```
    const natInstance1 = new CfnInstance(this, 'NatInstance1', {
      imageId: NAT_AMI_ID,
      instanceType: NAT_INSTANCE_TYPE,
      subnetId: vpc.publicSubnets[0].subnetId,
      keyName: NAT_SSH_KEY,
      sourceDestCheck: false,
      securityGroupIds: [ 
        publicSecurityGroup.securityGroupId
      ]
    });

    new ec2.CfnEIPAssociation(this, 'NatEip1', {
      eip: NAT_EIP_POOL[0],
      instanceId: natInstance1.instanceId
    });
```

This no longer works in v0.37.0, get error: `Property 'instanceId' does not exist on type 'CfnInstance'.ts(2339)`

Answer (score 5):

The question was raised as aws-cdk [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3225)  and answered. Here the the code snippet taken from the linked answer:

```
new ec2.CfnEIPAssociation(this, 'NatEip1', {
  eip: NAT_EIP_POOL[0],
  instanceId: natInstance1.ref
});
```

Comment: `.ref` is nice tip. Thanks